# Horizontal align don't work when vertical aligned

Tags: html, css, center

I am working on a simple responsive layout, I got it vertical aligned but I can't get it horizontal aligned. It is probably very simple but even my co workers can't get it to work.

The page is: http://jorzwa.nl/heracles/

Comment: You get this headache because you use `table` displays for your `html` and `body` tags. Things might seem not intuitive when using these displays.

Comment: Where is your code? Please provide an [mcve] rather than expecting us to trawl through the source of your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set both `html`, `body`, and `.container` to `width: 100%`